# WordPress: Get child taxonomies only from one level down

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display the WooCommerce sub-categories based on the current category ID.

To get all sub-categories, I'm using the following code to get all child IDs.
The problem is, that I get all levels below the current category.

Is there any way to limit the categories to only the next level?
For example: Level 1 only gets categories from level 2, and level 2 only from level 3.

Here's my code (it's from the WordPress docs):

```
$term_id = $productcat_id;
$taxonomy_name = 'product_cat';
$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $child, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Have you tried putting an `if()` statement in your `foreach` to check if `$child` parent `category_id` is `==`  to `$term_id` ? That way you can control what you echo

Comment: or https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/124429

Comment: perfect, thank you. If you post it as answer, I will accept it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As taken from https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/124429

You could do

```
$term_children = get_terms(
    'product_cat',
     array(
        'parent' => get_queried_object_id(),
     )
);

if ( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
        $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $child ) . '">' . $child->name . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```